# What to do after cURL? Or, best way to parse strings with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to grab content from a website, parse it, extract what I want, and put it in a database.

I'm using PHP.

I've built a script using cURL that goes through the pages I need and grabs the HTML content. Now, from what I understand, I need a tool or library that will allow me to take that string full of the page's HTML and parse it.

Any tips on how (best) to do that with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to follow HTML structure, use `DOM` extension. Use method [`loadHTML`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load the data and then you can use the data either as [DOMDocument](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or [SimpleXML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) document (use `simplexml_import_dom` to convert).

If you just need to extract some stuff and not bother with understanding document structure, use [regular expressions](http://php.net/pcre).